Which is correct way to measure FPS of pytorch model?
When I am using this code then I am getting almost same values of FPS by cuda event (8.7 FPS) and pref_counter (8.8 FPS)
    model.to(device)

    w , h = 640, 640
    dummy_input = torch.randn(200, 1, 3, w, h, dtype=torch.float).to(device)

    steps, repetitions = 10, 100
        # allocating 40MB to match L2 cache size on A100
    x = torch.empty(int(40 * (1024 ** 2)), dtype=torch.int8, device='cuda')

    def flush_cache():
        x.zero_()

    # Warmup steps
    for i in range(steps):
        _ = model(dummy_input[i]) # don't record time

    start_events = [torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True) for _ in range(repetitions)]
    end_events = [torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True) for _ in range(repetitions)]

    for i in tqdm(range(repetitions), desc='Progress'):
        flush_cache()
        torch.cuda._sleep(1_000_000)

        start_events[i].record()
        _ = model(dummy_input[i])
        end_events[i].record()

    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    times = [s.elapsed_time(e) for s, e in zip(start_events, end_events)]

    # reset_clock_speed()
    
    mean_syn = np.sum(times) / repetitions
    fps = 1000 / mean_syn

    print("Average Inference time: {:.4f} ms".format(mean_syn))
    print("Average FPS {} x {}: {:.4f}".format(w, h, fps))

    # Warmup steps
    for i in range(steps):
        _ = model(dummy_input[i]) # don't record time

    t = 0
    for i in tqdm(range(repetitions), desc='Progress'):
        s = time.perf_counter()
        _ = model(dummy_input[i])
        e = time.perf_counter()
        t += (e-s)

    fps = 100/t
    print("Average FPS {} x {}: {:.4f}".format(w, h, fps))

But If i add torch.cuda.empty_cache() in pref_counter method then FPS in pref_counter method becomes 34.8.
    for i in tqdm(range(repetitions), desc='Progress'):
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        s = time.perf_counter()
        _ = model(dummy_input[i])
        e = time.perf_counter()
        t += (e-s)

    fps = 100/t
    print("Average FPS {} x {}: {:.4f}".format(w, h, fps))

So which is correct and why is this happening. Can anyone please help?
I have tried to include torch.cuda.empty_cache() in cuda event also, but FPS remains the same in cuda event method.

What happens if you include the time that empty_cache takes in the count? Ie likely the code must periodically empty the cache automatically so by explicitly calling this function you're moving the time it takes outside of the timed section of code
